# Concatenate select box selected values

Tags: javascript, jquery, each

Thanks in advance! I am building an application using asp.net web form that have one dropdownlist and two listbox, which needs to be clone whenever a button is click. My problem is I'm currently hard coding a lot of code and I will like to make it more dynamic. Can everyone help me figure this out?

Here is an example of what my current script is doing.
[image]

Code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var clone = (function() {
    var cloneIndex = 0;
    var template = $('#categoryTemplate').text();

    return function() {
      return template.replace(/ID/g, ++cloneIndex);
    }
  })();

  //Start off with 1 category.
  categories.append(clone());

  var sbClone1 = new StringBuilder();

  $(document).on('change', '#MainContent_ddlWarehouse1', function () {
      var myele = '';
      sbClone1.strings[0] = [];
      var mystring = '';
      myele = $(this).val();
      sbClone1.strings[0] = 'SELECT top 10 ' + myele + ', PART_CODE, WAREHOUSE, UNIT_OF_MEASURE, MOVEMENT_DATE, MOVEMENT_CODE, [IC_MOVE_QUANTITY] FROM [dbo].[IC_MOVEMENTS] WHERE MOVEMENT_DATE between "' + startDateTextBox.val() + '" and "' + endDateTextBox.val() + '" AND WAREHOUSE = "' + myele + '" ';
      mystring = sbClone1.toString();

     $('#MainContent_hfConcatString').val(mystring);
     document.getElementById("MainContent_Label1").innerHTML = mystring;
   });

   $(document).on('change', '#MainContent_lbMovementCode1', function () {
       var myele = '';
       sbClone1.strings[1] = [];
       var mystring = '';
       myele = $(this).val();
       sbClone1.strings[1] = 'AND MOVEMENT_CODE IN "' + myele + '" ';
       mystring = sbClone1.toString();

       $('#MainContent_hfConcatString').val(mystring);
       document.getElementById("MainContent_Label1").innerHTML = mystring;
   });

   $(document).on('change', '#MainContent_lbUnitofMeasure1', function () {
      var myele = '';
      sbClone1.strings[2] = [];
      var mystring = '';
      myele = $(this).val();
      sbClone1.strings[2] = ' AND UNIT_OF_MEASURE IN "' + myele + '" ';
      mystring = sbClone1.toString();

      $('#MainContent_hfConcatString').val(mystring);
      document.getElementById("MainContent_Label1").innerHTML = mystring;
  });

  $(document).on("click", 'button.add', function() {
    categories.append(clone());
  });
});

<script type="text/template" id="categoryTemplate">
    <div class="category" id="DatasetID"> 
        <div class="row">
            <!-- Warehouse Category -->
            <div class="col col-lg-4">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label" for="WarehouseID">Warehouse</label>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlWarehouseID" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="true">
                        <asp:ListItem Value="0" Text="Please Select"></asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </div>
            </div>
             <!-- MovementCode Category -->
            <div class="col col-lg-4">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label" for="MovementCodeID">Movement Code</label>
                    <asp:ListBox ID="lbMovementCodeID" runat="server" SelectionMode="Multiple">
                    </asp:ListBox>
                </div>
            </div>
             <!-- UnitofMeasure Category -->
            <div class="col col-lg-4">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label" for="UnitofMeasureID">Unit of Measure</label>
                    <asp:ListBox ID="lbUnitofMeasureID" runat="server" SelectionMode="Multiple">
                    </asp:ListBox>
                </div>
            </div>          
        </div>
    </div>
</script>
```

Comment: I hope this addition was able to clarify my question

Comment: @Paul What is the problem?

Comment: Ideally I will like to use the selected value/values from all three select elements as inputs to a select statement.

Comment: Could you please explain where the selected values are put into the SELECT query?

Answer (score -1):

There is no need to iterate through the options, try following:

```
var string = $("[name=cars]").val().join(", ")
```